# Параллельный импорт .py-файлов

Tags: python, импорт

В процессе написания кода столкнулся с проблемой параллельного импорта. Мне необходимо написать код в одном скрипте под названием file_1. В данном файле присутствует несколько параметров:

```
a_1=1.12*10**(-8)
a_2=1.12*10**(-7)
a_3=1.12*10**(-6)
a_4=1.12*10**(-5)
```

Они будут импортироваться в скрипт file_2, и преобразовываться по схеме:

```
a_1=1/file_1.a_1
a_2=1/file_1.a_2
a_3=1/file_1.a_3
a_4=1/file_1.a_4
```

Затем в скрипте file_2 преобразованные значения будут использоваться в серии расчётов, где на выходе получится массив данных для отображения на графике: список значений x по оси x, и список значений Txt по оси y.
Далее я импортирую данные значения из file_2 обратно в file_1 следующим путём:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(file_2.x, file_2.Txt_1, label = 'a, м2/с =1.12*10^(-8)')
ax.plot(file_2.x, file_2.Txt_2, label = 'a, м2/с =1.12*10^(-7)')
ax.plot(file_2.x, file_2.Txt_3, label = 'a, м2/с =1.12*10^(-6)')
ax.plot(file_2.x, file_2.Txt_4, label = 'a, м2/с =1.12*10^(-5)')
ax.set(xlabel='x/L, д.е.', ylabel='dT/(E*dP), д.е.', title='dT/(E*dP)')
ax.grid()
legend = ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Выдаётся ошибка:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'file_2' has no attribute 'x' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

То есть, по сути, задача состоит в том, чтобы file_1 сделать просто несколько скорректированным отображением работы file_2, но, как я понимаю, импортировать скрипты друг в друга одновременно возможным не представляется. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: выноси такие вещи в отдельный файл.

Comment: @eri , я вот вынес в file_2 фактический код, а в file_1 корректированный, не совсем понимаю про что вы

Comment: attribute 'x' вынеси в file_3

Comment: Оформите код в file_2 как функции, а вызов и возврат будут из них  в file_1.